# ERRORS with INCLUDE_ONCE Global Variable PHP

Tags: php

I created a config file that has a variable I want to use as a constant.

```
<?php
$ROOT_PATH = 'C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site';
?>
```

On a CLASS page where I want to use the variable I added the following before instantiating the CLASS:

```
include_once("config.php");
$root=$ROOT_PATH;
```

I made the appropriate scoping changes to the functions in my class as follows:
    global $root;
    include_once($root."/Library/API/database.inc.php");

When I run my app, it **DOES** perform all of the data connections it
 is designed to do, BUT it **STILL** returns the following errors:

> Warning: include_once(config.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in
>   C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site'\class\Posting.class.php on
>   line 5
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'config.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site'\class\Posting.class.php on
>   line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: ROOT_PATH in
>   C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site'\class\Posting.class.php on
>   line 6
>
> Warning: include_once(/Library/API/database.inc.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site'\class\Posting.class.php on
>   line 112
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/Library/API/database.inc.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site'\class\Posting.class.php on
>   line 112
>
> Warning: include_once(/Library/API/database.inc.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site'\class\Posting.class.php on
>   line 112
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/Library/API/database.inc.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site'\class\Posting.class.php on
>   line 112

If I comment out the include and hard code the $root it runs like before BUT it **DOES NOT** throw any errors:

```
#include_once("joblaunch.php");
#$root=$ROOT_PATH;
$root='C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site';
```

I don't understand why it runs and throws errors when getting the variable from the config.php but runs and doesn't throw an error when hard coding the path.

Comment: Why don't you just use `define('ROOT_PATH', 'C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site');` and use `ROOT_PATH`. Then you won't have any scoping problems.

Comment: Also, you need to put `global $root` inside the functions that use it. Not in the global scope.

Comment: So for example: if you have functions in your `database.inc.php` file, then the `global $root` has to go inside those functions. Not before you include the file.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I tried this (I already had the global $root in the functions). See my comment below.

Comment: It looks like your script isn't even including the `config.php` file. The first error says it didn't find it. That's why it's not recognizing your config variable. Are you sure `config.php` is in the same directory?

Comment: @KodosJohnson It definitely finds it because the calls that use it run. They didn't without the include statement or a change in the path statement. The issue is that it throws the error as if it didn't see it.

Comment: It looks like Posting.class.php is trying to include `config.php` but it fails. Can you show the code in that file that includes it?

Comment: @KodosJohnson Not sure what code you want me to show. The include statement (shown above) or the code in the config.php, or something else?

Comment: So the code you showed above is in your `Posting.class.php` file? If that is the case, is your `config.php` file located in your `class` folder?

Comment: `include_once` is relative to the current directory. So if you call `include_once` from `Posting.class.php`, then the `config.php` file must be in the `class` folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you define a constant instead of a variable, this problem should be solved,

**definition**

old:

```
$ROOT_PATH = 'C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site';
```

new:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', 'C:/Users/me/Documents/app-qas.com/site');
```

**usage**

old:

```
$root=$ROOT_PATH;
```

new:

```
$root = ROOT_PATH;
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and the same thing occurs. I changed the config.php to the define statement. I changed the other file to $root = ROOT_PATH;, The error message is the same except the NOTICE which is now: Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH'